# Is a straight line the shortest distance between two points?

Tags: differential-geometry

Quite simply, I heard a lot of talk about how a straight line isn't necessarily the shortest distance between two points.

Is this true, and if it isn't, how would that work?

Comment: That's not a physics question, it's pure geometry. The entire field of [Riemannian geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_geometry) is about spaces where the shortest line is not "straight".

Comment: I would agree that this is not a physics question but argue that a closely related one. At least as physical as say calculating the trajectory of a projectile.

Comment: @bytec0de : Define 'straight line'.

Comment: In terms of physics, the path of ray of light in vacuum is the shortest distance between two points.

Comment: @bytecode: a geodesic is the shortest way to get from here to there; on a plane this is a straight line, but on the surface of the earth it's a [great circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle).  In General Relativity it is a null geodesic, which is the path followed by a ray of light.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about physics, and I consider it of too low quality to migrate it.

Comment: @Harsh, 15 tag edits in a matter of minutes is a little excessive. It floods the front page, pushing out other questions. Please, if you're going to go on an editing spree, do three or four a day, not 15 an hour.

Comment: @Qmechanic A straight line does not have curves, so "every A->B vector on it has the same direction". It is funny though that you can define it as "every A-B distance on it is the shortest possible distance" too if you accept that the shortest path is always on a straight line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a very non-technical answer: If our space was Euclidean then a straight line would be the shortest distance between two points. And until Einstein, through his general theory of relativity, showed that the space can actually be bent everybody believed and treated the space as Euclidean.

But now we know that the "physical" space is not Euclidean and therefore a straight line is not necessarily the shortest distance between two points. Consider for example being on the surface of a solid (impenetrable) sphere. The shortest distance between two points on the sphere is not a straight line.

I recommend you to read about geodesics.

Comment: _"The shortest distance between two points on the sphere is not a straight line."_ It's not straight when embedded in a 3D Euclidean space, but on the surface of a sphere those lines are as straight as it gets.

Comment: Actually, even Special Relativity requires a non-Euclidean space-time.  Euclidean space and the space of Special Relativity have different metrics.  Special Relativity space-time is given the name Minkowski Space.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that space is Euclidean in special relativity. Its spacetime that's non-Euclidean.

Comment: I think an example with some math would be a nice addition.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall what I've seen from Neil deGrasse Tyson correctly, he said that for what we currently have observed in the universe, a straight line is the shortest distance between two points. However, something that we have very healthily theorized about is worm holes. If worm holes exist, then you can travel through the worm hole to potentially travel less distance to get to the same point.

Think about it like a piece of paper. Of course, if you draw two points on opposite ends of the piece of paper, the least distance pathway is to draw a straight line connecting the two. What wormholes would do is what he describes as folding the piece of paper. So, if you fold the piece of paper so the points are closer, the least distance pathway would be using the worm hole instead of travelling along the piece of paper.

Comment: The first point is already incorrect, since geodesics in GR are mostly not straight lines. The eye will perceive them as straight lines, but that's because our brain implicitly makes the assumption that light travels in straight lines.

Comment: Also if you have a wormhole you can just draw a new straight line which is shorter so the statement still holds.

Comment: @Martin: your *"geodesics in GR are mostly not straight lines"* contradicts *" Insofar as the term straight line has any meaning in curved spacetime it means a geodesic"* [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/211697/12613) - this confuses me.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: No, it doesn't. "Insofar as the term straight line has any meaning". That's just it - it rarely has any meaning. Hence geodesics are no straight lines. The problem here lies with the definition of "straight line". If you don't have any idea about non-Euclidean geometry, a straight line means a Euclidean straight line. The thing you draw on a flat piece of paper with a ruler. In non-Euclidean geometry, this is often not possible, so people sometimes might define "straight line" to refer to geodesics, i.e. shortest connections between two points.

Comment: I mean, it's not possible to draw a straight line as in "that thing you draw with a ruler on a piece of paper" on a sphere. You'll have to draw great circles - and circles are definitely not the Euclidean version of "straight line".

Comment: @Martin: Thanks, I think that's clearer for me. I was already aware of great-circles, gravitational-lensing and had read related answers here on straight-lines and GR etc. I think it might be less confusing if everybody just stated that the term "straight line" has no real meaning in curved spacetime.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: I think the problem is that people like the concept of "straight line" - so they want to find the analogue of that. Since you can also define straight lines in Euclidean geometry by "shortest Euclidean distance between two points" that gives you the geodesic as a good analogon and that's why people talk about "straight lines" in that way.